# is there any tool can give me 8-3 short name for a long directory name

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, command-line

For example, I want to know the 8-3 name for c:\program files(x86\test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open `Command Prompt` (`cmd.exe`) and type:

```
dir /x c:\anyfolder
```

It'll output the directory contents with short filenames in a separate column